# Parar a execução de uma função assíncrona

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, sou meio novo no universo do JavaScript e seu assincronismo. Tenho a seguinte função assíncrona abaixo. Ao entrar na condição "!= null", desejo que ela seja encerrada e as funções seguintes não sejam executadas. Porém um "return" simplesmente não está funcionando.

```
async function register() {
            await checkExists(id)
                .then(string => {
                    if(string != null) {
                        // return - parar a execução do resto aqui;
                    }
                })

            await getString(id)
                .then(string => {
                    // Próxima função...
                })
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Acho que existe uma pequena falta de detalhe no entendimento das async functions, não podemos parar uma async function pois ela já foi adicionada a cadeia de execução pelo o event loop a quando a interpretação.

Ou seja não podes parar este loop mas podes pedir para sair do processo do teu server com `process.exit()`

Mas esta solução vai te causar outros problemas como fugas ou erros de estado, tenta pesquisar sobre geradores e sobre yield.

Answer (score -4):

oii, espero que funcione para você. Se quiser pode avançar e refatorar para não precisar deixar o if/else, mas como você é novo no js deixei o código o mais legível.

```js
async function register() {
  await checkExists(id).then((string) => {
    if (string !== null) {
      return;
    } else {
      pegaString();
    }
  });
}

await function pegaString() {
  await getString(id).then((string) => {
    // Próxima função...
  });
};
```